# deny access to a certain location nginx

Tags: nginx

In my nginx error log is the following message:

> FastCGI sent in stderr: "Unable to open primary script: /www//vb/showthread.php

My site is not made with vb and so I want to deny any requests to /vb/ how can I do that?
I experimented with

```
location /vb/ {
deny all;
}
```

but I still see many such errors in my error log, it looks like spam requests.

How can I also prevent access to `/wp-loging.php` and such?

I find the double // in the error log strange and I can't understand it.

here's my server config:

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  www.domain.com;

    #charset koi8-r;

    #access_log  logs/nattiq.access.log  main;

    location / {
        root /home/www;
        index  index.php;
        try_files $uri @rewrite;
    }
    location //vb/showthread.php {
         deny all;
         }
         location /wp-login.php {
              deny all;
              }
    #error_page  404              /404.html;

    # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
    #
    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root /home/www;
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
proxy_set_header Connection "";
    }

    # proxy the PHP scripts to Apache listening on 127.0.0.1:80
    #
    #location ~ \.php$ {
    #    proxy_pass   http://127.0.0.1;
    #}

    # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
    #
      location @rewrite {
rewrite ^ /index.php;
```

}

```
    location ~ \.php$ {
        root /home/www;
    #    fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
 fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;        
        fastcgi_index  index.php;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root/$fastcgi_script_name;
        include        fastcgi_params;
            fastcgi_read_timeout 150;
```

Comment: You should update your question and add your `nginx` server configuration.

Comment: something like :location ~ ^/download/(.*)$ { worked but I get 
access forbidden by rule in the logs. any better way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The double `//` is because of SCRIPT_FILENAME, which should actually look like this:

```
fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
```

Rather that trying to block individual `.php` files that do not exist, you should prevent any fake `.php` file from being transmitted upstream by the addition of one line at the top of the `location ~ \.php$` block:

```
try_files $uri =404;
```

See [this document](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/tutorials/config_pitfalls/#passing-uncontrolled-requests-to-php) for details.